# При добавлении зависимостей крашится Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.1</version>
</dependency>
```

и так
pom

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.accenture.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>flowerShopNew</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>flowerShopNew Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> 
    <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
    <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 1 Repository (legacy)</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
        <layout>legacy</layout>
    </repository> 
  </repositories> 
  <properties>
  <jersey.version>2.24.1</jersey.version>
  <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version> 
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <finalName>flowerShopNew</finalName>
  <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
          <configuration>
           <sourse>1.8</sourse>
           <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin> 


</plugins>
```

application-context

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
   http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
   http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd ">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.accenture"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="flyway">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list><value>com.accenture</value></list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
         <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
         <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
     </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/flower" />

<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <array>
            <value>dbscript</value>
        </array>
   </property>
    <property name="baselineOnMigrate" value="true"/>
    <property name="outOfOrder" value="true"/>
    <property name="sqlMigrationPrefix" value="v"/>
    <property name="sqlMigrationSeparator" value="__"/>

    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="@{"/>
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Ошибка `invalid LOC header` наводит на мысль о битых jar'ах. Попробуйте удалить их из  ~/.m2/repository. Или снести весь локальный репозиторий. Лучше командой `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`.

Comment: теперь Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' причем непонятно с чего

Comment: `mvn clean package` после чистки репозитория делали, надеюсь?

Comment: mvn clean instal делал

Comment: как только убираю эти зависимости все работает,они могут конфликтовать с моими?

Comment: Нужен полный текст новой ошибки, полный листинг pom.xml и неплохо бы конфигурацию контекста Spring.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56655/discussion-between---and-sergey-gornostaev).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Вы используете Spring4, а `org.glassfish.jersey.ext.jersey-spring3` содержит в себе модули Spring3.